# SDL framework include on MacOS Qt

Tags: qt, frameworks, sdl

I want to compile a SDL project with Qt. I downloaded SDL framework 1.2.15 and here is my Qt project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
OBJECTIVE_HEADERS += SDLMain.h
OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += SDLMain.m
LIBS += -framework Cocoa
LIBS += -F/Library/Frameworks
LIBS += -framework SDL
```

When I compile with Qt 5.0.2, everything is fine but when I use Qt 5.1.0 I have the following error when compiling SDLMain.m :

```
error: 'SDL/SDL.h' file not found
```

Why Qt 5.1 doesn't handle framework in the same way that Qt 5.0.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it had previously worked, but let's note the following:

1. Addition of the framework to the `LIBS` only takes care of linking, not compilation.
2. You don't need the `INCLUDEPATH`, it's not necessary.
3. You need to add the frameworks path for both the linker and the compiler:

   ```
   // The directory where some frameworks are installed. There must
   // exist SDL.framework as a subdirectory of that directory.
   // It's simply to avoid typing the path twice.
   // It's a user variable, not interpreted by qmake
   SDL = -F/Library/Frameworks
   // Let the C/C++ compiler know where to find the frameworks.
   // This is so that when you include <xyz/foo>, it'll be replaced
   // by $$SDL/xyz.framework/Headers/foo
   // $$var is replaced by qmake by the contents of var
   QMAKE_CFLAGS += $$SDL
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$SDL
   // Since we compile some Objective C code, we need to set
   // the flags there too.
   QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += $$SDL
   QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CXXFLAGS += $$SDL
   // Let the linker know where to find the frameworks
   LIBS += $$SDL
   // Tell the linker that we want to use the SDL framework.
   LIBS += -framework SDL
   ```

This is tested on both OS X 10.6 and 10.8. Make sure you have xcode installed, and that it's the latest version available for given OS X. You should have

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

in your source.